# python plotly bar chart grouped and stacked in Jupyter-nb

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, stacked

I want to paint a bar chart where I can see 2 different levels in the same group, for example:

```
|pd.dataframe|category| col1    | col2   |
|  1         | row 1  |   3     |  7     |
|  1         | row 2  |   2     |  5     |
|  2         | row 1  |   2     |  ...   |
```

I would like to plot in the same image two columns together for each different index. In one column, I pretend to plot values of row_1 and row_2 in a related/stacked mode

```
bar1 = [3+7,2+5]
```

and plot in the second bar info of columns

```
bar2 = [3+2, 7+5]
```

plotting both in a grouped form

Here you can see an example. I found cases in plotly.js, but I can't find nothing about Python case.

Here you can see an example [image: An example found in GitHub, but for plotly.js]

Comment: Please try this https://community.plot.ly/t/combination-of-grouped-and-stacked-bar-chart/2154/3

Comment: It works, it's not perfect, but it's close. Thank you very much. Do you know how I can display the hover of each bar at the same side as bar?

Comment: Share the code that works and share the image what is expected as hover